# The proof of Crossbar Theorem

Tags: geometry

I read a geometry textbook and feel confuse about the following part:

Given a lemma as follows:

Given a line l and a point lying on l. For any Q not lying on l, points in line PQ\{P} are on the same side of l.

This is a useful lemma when you proof Crossbar Theorem.

How can I proof this lemma? And how can I use it for the proof of Crossbar Theorem?

Comment: This seems false. In fact, removing P from line PQ should leave two rays, one on either side of line l.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Point $P$ lies on line $l$. (That's how I understand it, anyway $-$ the OP doesn't actually define $P$ at all!)

Comment: @TonyK Yes, and if you remove point P (where line PQ and line l intersect) from line PQ, you get the two rays I mentioned.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I see what you mean! But I am pretty sure that the OP means the _line segment_ $PQ$. OP, please make this clear!

Comment: @TonyK - The line segment $PQ$ or even the ray with origin in $P$ and passing through $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

The post contains a mistake. I suppose that the question is: the points in **half**line $PQ\backslash\{P\}$ are on the same side of $l$. $\;\;$[In the following I will denote by $P\rightsquigarrow Q$ the open halfline with origin at $P$ and containing $Q$]

Let us consider an equation of the affine line $l$ of the form

$$ f(X)=0 $$

where $f$ is an affine function from the affine space $\mathbb R^2$ to the affine space $\mathbb R$.
The function $f$ divides $\mathbb R^2$ into three parts: the line $l$, described precisely by $f(X)=0$, and two halfplanes described by $f(X)>0$ and $f(X)<0$, respectively. We can suppose, for example, that $Q$ lies in the halfplane $f(X)>0$. We have, therefore

$$ f(P)=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad f(Q)>0. $$

If $R\in P\rightsquigarrow Q$, then

$$ R-P = \lambda(Q-P) \qquad \text{for some  }\lambda>0 $$

and so, if we denote by $df$ the linear part of $f$ (sometimes denoted $\vec f$):

\begin{align}
f(R) &= f(R)-f(P) = df(R-P) =\\[1ex]
&= df(\lambda(Q-P)) =\\[1ex]
&= \lambda df(Q-P) =\\[1ex]
&= \lambda(f(Q)-f(P)) =\\[1ex]
&= \lambda f(Q)>0
\end{align}

i.e. $R$ is in the halfplane $f(X)>0$.
Vice versa, if $R$ is a point in $l$ (hence $R-P=\lambda(Q-P)$ with $\lambda\in\mathbb R$) and $f(R)>0$, then the preceeding calculation prove that $\lambda>0$, which implies $R\in P\rightsquigarrow Q$.

**Note**$\quad $ This result admits an immediate generalisation where $l$ is a hyperplane of a real affine space. The proof is essentially the same.

For a proof of the Crossbar Theorem, you can see, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3580533